# Send a (parallel) stream through a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to write a distributed Map-reduce program in java, using the Java 8 map-reduce framework, that has the following design:

One client sends data to 3 Mappers (each a different machine/standalone java application). The mappers work with the data in parallel by creating a `parallelStream()` from the List of data.

Now each mapper should call `.map(...)` on its parallelStream. Then, the idea is to send the mapped data to another node, the Reducer.

The reducer will get the Stream and call `.reduce(...)` on it and finally `.get()` to get the final results, that are sent back to the client.

My program works if I call `.map(...).reduce(...).get()` on the same program, but I want to be able to have a separate reducer node.

As I am new in socket programming and also at using Java 8, I'm having trouble sending the stream through the Socket, because it throws a "java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3" the moment I try to write the stream with `WriteObject`.

What's the best way to proceed here? Can I turn the stream into something else, send it and then turn it into a stream again on my `Reducer` node? Is there a better way to send the stream than through an `ObjectOutputStream`?

Any ideas are very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

P.S.: The stream is a `Stream<Map<String, Integer>>`.

Comment: You will need to dump out the stream to a normal collection or array.  You can't send the stream itself; it's computation, not data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. If I understand how Java 8 works,map(). and .reduce() should work together on the same machine right?

What I did, is I also called reduce, to create a Map, and then sent the Map to my "Reducer" which will join the 3 maps together. Is this a good practice?

Comment: Whatever you do with a `Stream` is local to that machine, and you should have finished whatever computation you want to do on that machine before you send it off somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I reduced the stream to a map that I sent to my reducer node, and everything is in working order now. Thanks again

Comment: Better solution that I found: I called '.collect(Collectors.toList())' on the Stream and sent that to my other node, and then done all the '.reduce()' procedures on my Reducer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to terminate the map node with a forEach that pushes data into the socket.  This strategy is superior to a collection approach if the collection could be very large (or theoretically infinite); it's space efficient, it's buffered, and down stream nodes are not idle waiting for collection process to complete.

Next wrap the socket reader for the reduce node in a Spliterator (extend AbstractSpliterator). The tryAdvance method of Spliterator reads data from the socket and makes it available to the stream through a caller provided Consumer. tryAdvance returns false when there is no more data (your end-of-stream marker, socket end of stream, or socket exception). AbstractSpliterator.trySplit implements limited parallelism.

Use StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator spliterator, boolean parallel) to construct a stream from your Spliterator implementation. Your reduce operation pulls its data from this stream.

You could retain the socket and your end-of-stream marker could be more like an end-of-message marker (reminds me of a batching pig in a pipeline).